# GHC can't determine type equality with GADTs and arrows

Tags: haskell, gadt, arrows

I'm having trouble getting GHC to notice that two types are equal in an arrow expression.

```
data PolyList a where
    Nil :: PolyList '[]
    Cons :: a -> PolyList as -> PolyList (a ': as)

class Recurse a where
    method :: PolyList a -> String

instance Recurse '[] where
    method _ = ""

instance (Show a, Recurse as) => Recurse (a ': as) where
    method = proc input -> case input of
        (Cons a as) -> do
            rest <- method -< as --Could not deduce (Recurse as)
            returnA -< show a ++ rest

    method = proc input -> case input of
        (Cons a as) -> do
            rest <- method -< as :: PolyList as --Works fine
            returnA -< show a ++ rest

    method (Cons a as) =
            let rest = method as --Also works
            in show a ++ rest
```

The full error is:

```
Could not deduce (Recurse as) arising from a use of `method'
from the context (Show a, Recurse as1)
  bound by the instance declaration
Possible fix:
  add (Recurse as) to the context of the instance declaration
```

Why can't it tell that `as` already has the type `PolyList as`?

EDIT: This ends up being kind of useless anyway because the fix appears to trigger [ghc #344](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/344), which is still not resolved. It would be good to know what the problem is.

Comment: If you replace the offending line with `rest <- _ -< as` and compile with ghc 7.8 it will crash when it tries to retrieve the type of the hole: `test.hs:18:42:ghc.exe: panic! (the 'impossible' happened)
  (GHC version 7.8.20140130 for x86_64-unknown-mingw32):
        No skolem info: as{tv a1zY} [ssk]`. It seems like this is a bug.